# no such file to load -- supermarket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want use the android-market-api jruby version.
But when i installed it and want use it.

it cause below load error.

I use https://github.com/jberkel/supermarket

java version is here: http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

who can help me?

```
$ rvm use jruby

$ gem install supermarket
Fetching: json-1.5.0-java.gem (100%)
Fetching: json-jruby-1.5.0-java.gem (100%)
Fetching: supermarket-0.0.5-universal-java.gem (100%)
Successfully installed json-jruby-1.5.0-java
Successfully installed supermarket-0.0.5-universal-java
3 gems installed

$ irb

jruby-1.6.5 :001 > require 'supermarket'
LoadError: no such file to load -- supermarket
      from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038:in `require'
      from (irb):1:in `evaluate'
      from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1088:in `eval'
      from /home/grant/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:158:in
`eval_input'
      from /home/grant/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in
`signal_status'
      from /home/grant/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in
`eval_input'
      from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1420:in `loop'
      from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1192:in `catch'
      from /home/grant/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in
`eval_input'
      from /home/grant/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in
`start'
      from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1192:in `catch'
      from /home/grant/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in
`start'
      from /home/grant/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5/bin/irb:17:in `(root)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first:

```
irb(main):003:0> require 'supermarket'
LoadError: no such file to load -- supermarket
```

but then:

```
irb(main):004:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):005:0> require 'supermarket'
=> true
```

You have to first `require` the `rubygems` to have the `require` command work the rubygems way.

**UPDATE** as it was pointed out in comments by @RobertRouse you can achieve the same effect by running `jirb` in the `--1.9` mode:

```
$ jruby --1.9 -S irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'supermarket'
=> true
```

Comment: Additionally, if you want to run jruby in 1.9 mode, set JRUBY_OPTS to --1.9 or pass --1.9 on the command line. That would make the require work without the explicit rubygems require. Depends on your needs

Comment: you can pass `--1.9` to `jruby`, `jirb` doesn't seem to have this switch

Comment: Pavel, you just have to expand it a bit: jruby --1.9 -S irb

Comment: You also need to have jruby installed: http://jruby.org/getting-started (rvm install jruby)